# Making a Div parallax

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have div that I want to stay put so that the navbar and the rest would just pass by it.

Here's my current work:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" class="img-responsive center-block">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080 " class="img-responsive center-block">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="headerCaption">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/CaptionBg.png') }}" id="curve" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="navbar-main">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}"></a>
            </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Sign Up/Login</a></li>
                </ul>

            <!-- Nav links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-section">
                    <li class="current active">
                        <a href="#carousel">First Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-2">Second Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-3">Third Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- End of navbar collapse -->
        </div><!-- End of Container Fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

I don't know if could do this using css only or what but I need it to be stay put. And if possible can be reused by other divs too. I hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SO Snippet. The shows how to accomplish what you are asking.

The magic is the **css attribute** *position:fixed;*. Well, ok, not so much magic but it works. Set your div to a fixed position used left, right, top, bottom, width and height attributes give it an actual position and shape. It's that easy.

Just see how they different classes work just change the class on the fixed div to one of the four classes I've defend as an example.

Hope this helps,

Tim

```css
div.fixed-top-left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

div.fixed-top-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

div.fixed-bottom-right {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

div.fixed-bottom-left {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-top-left holder">
   This is a fixed div
</div>

<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="navbar-main">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}"></a>
            </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Sign Up/Login</a></li>
                </ul>

            <!-- Nav links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-section">
                    <li class="current active">
                        <a href="#carousel">First Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-2">Second Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-3">Third Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- End of navbar collapse -->
        </div><!-- End of Container Fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```